# DataFrame.write.parquet() throws NPE

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

source DataFrame: a csv with `spark-csv`,which comes from `maven`

```
sqlctx.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load(FileName)
```

After read it i tried `DataFrame.printSchema()` which shows good

And when doing `DataFrame.write.parquet(path)`, it crashed with NPE throwed, messages are following:

```
16/02/01 15:43:59 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 59)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:656)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:490)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:462)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:428)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:889)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:786)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:176)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:160)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:289)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:262)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetRelation.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anon$3.newInstance(ParquetRelation.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:129)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:255)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/02/01 15:43:59 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 59, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:482)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:808)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:791)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:656)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:490)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:462)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:428)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:889)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:786)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:176)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:160)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:289)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:262)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetRelation.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anon$3.newInstance(ParquetRelation.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:129)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:255)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Environment:NPE only happens in windows, all codes runs fine in linux

P.S: DataFrame.write.save() shows the same NPE, is this a win spec problem?

Comment: are you writing to HDFS or Windows File system? How are you specifying the path? specifically if you are writing it in Raw file system?

Comment: also,`sqlctx.read.parquet(path)` throws NPE. I guess spark generates the wrong path

Comment: @Sumit  FS is ntfs on windows. path is relative, one of them is  ` "data\\Index.parquet" `

Comment: Ran into the same problem when reading csv with spark-csv and saving a parquet file to windows file system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install winutils.exe in the hadoop installation mentioned in $HADOOP_HOME. You can obtain this installation from https://www.barik.net/archive/2015/01/19/172716/ which is a hadoop build with the winutils.exe in the bin folder. This resolves the NPE problem.